# Не могу поставить все в один ряд

Tags: html, css

```css
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.anim{
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: aqua;

}

nav li{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="logo"></div>
<div class="anim">
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a>home</a></li>
        <li><a>models</a></li>
    </ul>
    <figure align="center">
        <img src=".png" width="100">
    </figure>
    <ul>
        <li><a>help</a></li>
        <li><a>about</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
</div>
```

Заранее Спасибо

Comment: Чтобы вставить код, который можно выполнить, используйте `фрагмент кода на ...` сверху от ввода или же сочетание клавиш `Ctrl+M`.

Comment: Не пользуйтесь `align="center"` это давно устарело. Чтобы выровнять в ряд, посмотрите в сторону `display: flex`.

Comment: я пишу в css figure{ display:flex; } а лого не выравнивается в центр

Comment: Нет, вам нужен `flex` для `nav`. Дальше с вашей разметкой вы можете выставить просто `justify-content: space-between`.

Comment: спасибо я просто убрал ul и поставил то что вы говорили flex для nav

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот в таком варианте мы можем дать для нашего `nav` `display: flex` и указать `justify-content: space-between`.
Дальше для `ul` внутри `nav` нам тоже нужно задать `display: flex` и для всего этого задать `gap: 20px` - что будет отступом между элементами.

Добавлю: Если картинка будет по высоте больше чем меню, будет не очень красиво, если вы хотите выровнять все по центру (по вертикали), то нужно задать `align-items: center` для `nav`.

```css
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.anim{
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: aqua;
}

nav
{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  gap: 20px;
}

nav ul
{
  display: flex;
  gap: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="logo"></div>
<div class="anim">
  <nav>
      <ul>
          <li><a>home</a></li>
          <li><a>models</a></li>
      </ul>
      <figure align="center">
          <img src=".png" width="100">
      </figure>
      <ul>
          <li><a>help</a></li>
          <li><a>about</a></li>
      </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```